# How to get the mouse Co-ordinates relative to current screen or window ( no the whole page )

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I have an issue. I want to get the mouse pointer co-ordinates relative to current screen or window not from the whole page, using jQuery.

I tried using jQuery's event object pageX and pageY property but those return the coordinates relative to the whole page.

In simple words, I want to get the mouse pointer distance from the bottom edge of the screen not the page.
Any idea to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can get the x/y coordinates of the mouse pointer relative to the viewport from the clientX and clientY properties of jQuery's event object. If you need the distance from the right or bottom edge, subtract the pointer coordinates from suitable properties of window.screen.